# shadow spread is obstruct by SingleChildScrollView boundary in flutter(images attached)

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, I'm trying to create a container, inside SingleChildScrollView. when i create shadow of containers, it is a straight line which is due to the boundary of SingleChildScrollView.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35, left: 5, bottom: 10),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
              child: Container(
                height: 170,
                width: 120,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  gradient: const LinearGradient(colors: [
                    Colors.deepOrange,
                    Colors.orange,
                  ], transform: GradientRotation(120)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              child: Container(
                height: 170,
                width: 120,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  gradient: const LinearGradient(colors: [
                    Colors.deepOrange,
                    Colors.orange,
                  ], transform: GradientRotation(120)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(color: Colors.orange.shade200,offset: Offset(10,5),spreadRadius: 1,blurRadius: 100)
                  ]
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
              child: Container(
                height: 170,
                width: 120,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  gradient: const LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Colors.deepOrange,
                      Colors.orange,
                    ],
                    transform: GradientRotation(120),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

i have applied shadow to the second padding. here is the image and i circled the part which doest fit in the UI

[image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwk6g.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `clipBehavior: Clip.none` to the SingleChildScrollView. The default is Clip `Clip clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge`.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35, left: 5, bottom: 10),
    child: Row(),
);
```

Comment: It worked, i was looking for this exact property.